# Updating a MySQL row automatically when inserting new ones

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table like:

```
ID, Time, Value
0, 1534270260, 10
```

I would like to update `Value` on every new entry for a given `Time`. For example, if I insert a new row, it would be like this.

```
ID, Time, Value
0, 1534270260, 5
1, 1534270260, 5
```

If I insert two new rows, it would be like this:

```
ID, Time, Value
0, 1534270260, 3.33
1, 1534270260, 3.33
2, 1534270260, 3.33
```

I would like it to do that automatically. For example, every 5 minutes before that `Time`, do the math and update the rows

Any help on how to achieve this on MySQL?

Comment: Why not add a count column that you increment., then have your view do the division? With your current approach you will have rounding errors...

Comment: You mean like counting all rows that have same time, do the math and update the Value? The thing is I would like it to do that automatically, for example, every 5 minutes before that time, do the math and update the tables

Comment: Let the value be 10, and anyone using or displaying values will have to divide it properly. Instead of insert, just increment count instead. If it didn't exist, insert with count as 1 and value at whatever the sum of all should always be.

Comment: A trigger on inserts could solve this problem.

Comment: Your data is not normalized (you are repeating the information that the time 1534270260 has the value 3.33 several times). One effect of that is that keeping your data consistent is much harder (as you can see from your example). I'd rethink your data model. There are actually several alternatives, depending on what your data is representing (e.g.: is the base value always "10", do you need the ids or would just counting how often you found a specific time be equivalent, ...).